# Combine multiple mono QImage into a color QImage

Tags: qt, qimage

For a list of colors, I have a corresponding list of `QImage`, format mono. The mono images have been processed in such a way that a single pixel can be black from all images.

I would like to merge them into a color image.

I had 3 ideas.

**1.** Use image composition modes. I was unable to get it to work. (Editing to remove it, to clean up post...)

**2.** Use the mono images as masks for each of the colors when added to the destination.
I have no idea how to implement it.

**3.** Iterating through pixels - slow, the documentation says that pixel manipulation functions are slow...

This works:

```
// Creating destination image
// m_colors: list of (n+1) QCcolor (last one corresponding to background)
// m_images: list of n QImage, Format_Mono, all of the same size (as the destination)
// using indexed image for destination since I have a limited palette
QImage preview = QImage(rect.size().toSize(), QImage::Format_Indexed8);
int previewWidth  = preview.size().width();
int previewHeight = preview.size().height();
int colorsSize = m_colors.size();
for(int k = 0; k < colorsSize; ++k)
{
    preview.setColor(k, m_colors.at(k).rgb());
}
--colorsSize;

// combining images
for(int j = 0; j < previewHeight; ++j)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < previewWidth; ++i)
    {
        // set background color
        preview.setPixel(i, j, colorsSize);
        for(int k = 0; k < colorsSize; ++k)
        {
            QImage im = m_images.at(k);
            if(!im.isNull())
            {
                if(m_images.at(k).pixelIndex(i, j) == 0)
                {
                    preview.setPixel(i, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should at least improve this using [`scanLine()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scanLine), but don't know how... I can only find examples that use `scanLine()` with 32 bit images, not 8 or 2.
Is it actually possible to use `scanLine()` with 8 or 2 bit images ?

I don't understand the documentation - does it mean that only 32 bit images can be read/written using `scanLine()` or that regardless of image type, the function will work the same way, and I only use one of the 4 bytes ?
Would be more effective to use 32 bit images instead of 8 or 2 bit ?

If I use 32 bit image for destination, and try to use `scanLine()` to write data, still how can I improve my reading of the mono images ?

Please help me improve my algorithm, either to improve the version that I get to work iterating through all pixels of images, or perhaps using some tools like combining images using composition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the result to look like. Non 32 bit image formats use a color table, see [Pixel Manipulation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#pixel-manipulation).

Comment: Additional information is also in the described under [Format enum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#Format-enum).

Comment: Exactly - the first section in my code fills the color table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it actually possible to use scanLine() with 8 or 2 bit images ?

Yes it is.

> Would be more effective to use 32 bit images instead of 8 or 2 bit ?

You will have to measure, and it will depend on the specific code. I used 8 bit code here for simplicity and because your code did.

> If I use 32 bit image for destination, and try to use scanLine() to write data, still how can I improve my reading of the mono images ?

It is probably not a good idea to copy the image in the inner loop

```
QImage im = m_images.at(k)
```

and to then not use that copy for the next access.

```
if(m_images.at(k).pixelIndex(i, j) == 0)
```

It should speed up your painting if your inner loop iterates over an image instead of iterating over the destination pixels in the inner loop.

If the image is monochrome, then the scan line will point to packed color information which will need to be unpacked. It is easier (and maybe faster) to let `convertToFormat` convert the image and then use `scanLine` to read the unpacked information. In the example below the images are all 8 bit.

```
#include<vector>

#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <QtGui/QColor>

static char * img1[] = { 
   "5 5 2 1", "a c #000000", "b c #ffffff",
   "aabba", "aabba", "aabba", "aabba", "aabba"
};

static char * img2[] = {
   "5 5 2 1","a c #000000","b c #ffffff",
   "aaaaa", "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "bbbbb", "aaaaa"
};

int main( int argc, char* arg[] )
{
   auto images = std::vector<QImage>( 2 );
   images[0] = QImage( img1 );
   images[1] = QImage( img2 );

   auto colors = std::vector<QColor>( 2 );
   colors[0] = QColor( Qt::red );
   colors[1] = QColor( Qt::green );

   QImage combined = QImage( images[0].size(), QImage::Format_Indexed8 );
   combined.setColor( 0, Qt::black );
   combined.fill(0);

   for( int k = 1, num = images.size(); k <= num; ++k )
   {
      combined.setColor( k, colors[k-1].rgb() );
      QImage img= images[k-1];

      for( int i = 0, height = img.height(); i < height ; ++i )
      {
         uchar* src = img.scanLine(i);
         uchar* dst = combined.scanLine(i);

         for( int j = 0, width = mono.width(); j < width; ++j )
         {
            if( src[j] != 0 ) 
               dst[j] = k;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. As for the copying image and not using it... `if(m_images.at(k).pixelIndex(i, j) == 0)` - I meant to use it, I have been making continuous changes. Doesn't the `fill()` take an extra full pass ? That's why I included it in the loop.

Comment: Yes it will take a pass, but it will still be faster than the i*j calls to `setPixel`